# How do we install D365 apps in powerapps environment with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powerapps

I need to install D365 apps to my powerapps environment with PowerShell. But, I don’t see any supported cmdlet available now.
Anyone please confirm, if any cmdlet is available to achieve the same in below use cases

1. Install D365 apps(Sales, Service etc) while creating the powerapps environment
   or
2. Install D365 apps for existing powerapps environment

Comment: Please learn [ask], then edit your question and post your code so far.

Answer (score 1):

I’m sharing this snippet from a [community forum thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/383373/help-to-create-a-new-d365-sales-professional-instance):

```
1   Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell
2   New-AdminPowerAppEnvironment -DisplayName "MyTestEnvironment" -EnvironmentSku Production -LocationName europe -CurrencyName EUR -LanguageName 1033 -Templates @("D365_SalesPro") -ProvisionDatabase
```